# Putting the cursor in text box after validating in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a basic ASP.NET website which has a register page with the user name, password and email as text boxes. Only one of them, the email, has a validation which is the default email validation from ASP.NET.
After the validation, I want the cursor to be in the email textbox if the validation fails.
Currently the message is displayed but the cursor is not on the page.

```
                                                <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" CssClass="cpTextBox" TextMode="Password"
                                                        TabIndex="7" ToolTip="Password must be at least six characters in length"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                                                        ErrorMessage="Please enter password" Display="None">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                                                        ErrorMessage="Password must be at least six characters in length" ValidationExpression=".{6,50}"
                                                        Display="None">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" CssClass="cpTextBox" TabIndex="11"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblVerifyPassword" runat="server" CssClass="cpLabel" Text="Verify password"></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" CssClass="cpLabel" Text="Phone"></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtVerifyPassword" runat="server" CssClass="cpTextBox" TextMode="Password"
                                                        TabIndex="8"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvConfirmPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtVerifyPassword"
                                                        ErrorMessage="Please verify the password" Display="None">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvVerifyPassword" runat="server" ControlToCompare="txtPassword"
                                                        ControlToValidate="txtVerifyPassword" ErrorMessage="Please verify the password"
                                                        Display="None">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                                                </td>
```

Can someone guide me on how to do this?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the validator control please set `SetFocusOnError="true"`